# How long can I keep peanut powder?

Tags: storage-lifetime

I like putting peanut flavor in my sauces and wanted to make a big batch of crushed and pulverized peanuts.

I was wondering how long I could keep these, before they went bad.

Comment: I  know not the question but why not just get a bullet grinder and pulverize on demand?  It is fast, fresh, and easy.

Comment: I wouldn't call it easy. Having to set it up, peel the nuts etc. Just another step I'd like to avoid. And I'm only cooking for one most of the time.

Comment: @paparazzo I also just found Peanut-Sauce powder in my Asia store. :)

Answer (score 3):

There are no safety concerns here. Baked and shelled peanuts are shelf stable, no matter if they are pulverized or not. Just smell before each use and discard once it turns rancid.

Comment: More surface area would cause it to go rancid more quickly.